# My html data isn't displayed because of my javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i started to build a basic website as a practice, and i got until i have a basic html, containing a table of informations, and a form, where you can add to the html through javascript.
My html looks like this

```
<body>

    <hr>
    <p class="display-4 text-center">Termék lista</p>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Termék Név</th>
            <th scope="col">Termék Azonosító</th>
            <th scope="col">Termék Ár</th>
            <th scope="col">Termék leírás</th>
            <th scope="col">Raktáron</th>
            <th scope="col">Törlés</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr>
            <td>mangó</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>499 Ft</td>
            <td>Gyümi</td>
            <td>Van</td>
            <td> <button class="delete btn btn-primary">X</button> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="bg-success p-5">
            <form id="input-form">
              <p class="display-4 text-center">Termékek hozzáadása</p>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputProduct">Termék</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProduct" name="productName">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputCode">Termék Azonosító</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputCode" name="productCode">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPrice">Termék Ára</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" name="productPrice">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <label for="inputDesc">Termék Leírás</label>
                    <select id="inputDesc" name="inputDesc">
                      <option value="Gyümölcs">Gyümölcs</option>
                      <option value="Zöldség">Zöldség</option>
                    </select>                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputSupply">Raktáron </label>
                    <select id="inputSupply" name="productSupply">
                      <option value="Van">Van</option>
                      <option value="Nincs">Nincs</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hozzáadás</button>
              </form>

        </div>

</div>
```

And this is my javascript code so far:

```
var products = [
    {
        productName:"körte",
        productCode: 2,
        productPrice: 30,
        productDesc: "Gyümi",
        productSupply: "Nincs",
        productId: 1
    },

    {
        productName: "répa",
        productCode: 3,
        productPrice: 20,
        productDesc: "Gyümi",
        productSupply: "Van",
        productId: 5
    },

    {
        productName: "paradicsom",
        productCode: 4,
        productPrice: 50,
        productDesc: "Gyümi",
        productSupply: "Nincs",
        productId: 6
    }
]
var table = '<tbody>'

for( i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
    table += `<tr>`;
    table += `<td>` + products[i].productName + `</td>`;
    table += `<td>` + products[i].productCode + `</td>`;
    table += `<td>` + products[i].productPrice + `</td>`;
    table += `<td>` + products[i].productDesc + `</td>`;
    table += `<td>` + products[i].productSupply + `</td>`;
    table += `<td> <button class="delete btn btn-primary" id="${products[i].productId}">X</button> </td>`
    table += '</tbody>';
}
document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML = table;


const tBody = document.getElementById("tbody")

tBody.addEventListener("click", function(x){
    console.log("remove from tomb");
    console.log(x.target);
    console.log("gomb id: " + x.target.id);
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

        console.log("tomb i id: " + products[i].productId);
             if (x.target.id == products[i].productId) {
                 console.log("removed");
                products.splice(i, 1);
             }        
    }

    if(x.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
        x.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();     
    }
    console.log(products);
})

const productInput = document.getElementById("inputProduct");
const codeInput = document.getElementById("inputCode");
const priceInput = document.getElementById("inputPrice");
const descInput = document.getElementById("inputDesc");
const supplyInput = document.getElementById("inputSupply");

const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

const addProduct = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let newProduct ={
        productName: document.getElementById("inputProduct").value,
        productCode: document.getElementById("inputCode").value,
        productPrice: document.getElementById("inputPrice").value,
        productDesc: document.getElementById("inputDesc").value,
        productSupply: document.getElementById("inputSupply").value,
        productId: Date.now()
    }

    let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.innerHTML += `
                <td>${newProduct.productName}</td>
                <td>${newProduct.productCode}</td>
                <td>${newProduct.productPrice}</td>
                <td>${newProduct.productDesc}</td>
                <td>${newProduct.productSupply}</td>
                <td> <button class="delete btn btn-primary" id="${newProduct.productId}">X</button> </td>`
    tBody.appendChild(newRow);

    products.push(newProduct);
    document.querySelector('form').reset();
    console.warn("added", {products});

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", addProduct)
})
```

The problem is, as you can see i already have a product in the html, but i think my javascript for function, which displays the data from the .js overwrited the data from the html, thus displaying only the 3 products from javascript var = products. How can i have both the html data and the javascript data displayed simultaneously, so i have all 4 products when i open my .html?

Comment: You can do it using appendChild().
Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

OR

You can try with insertRow();
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this line as following. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML += table;
```

Here is the output:

http://jsfiddle.net/3zd0y64n/